# How to Pass a List from c# to an oracle procedure

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a code that sends data as a string list from the textbox to oracle procedure.

I get the values in the textbox below.

```
      public List<string> TxtPieceList()
{

    List<string> pieces = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < txtListe.Lines.Count(); i++)
    {
        pieces.Add(txtListe.Lines[i]);
    }

    return pieces;
}
```

There are two variables I sent.

p_piece_id is assigned value from textbox.

p_mother_check is assigned value from checkbox.

Then I pass this data into the procedure :

```
 public void gridDoldur()
        {

            var annesecilimi = cbMother.Checked;

            List<string> gridList = TxtPieceList();
  using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Z_LABEL_PRINTER_GR.LabelPieceList", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                try
                {
                    OracleParameter p_piece_id = new OracleParameter();
                    OracleParameter p_mother_check = new OracleParameter();

                    p_piece_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                    p_mother_check.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                    p_piece_id.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                    p_mother_check.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
                    p_piece_id.Value = from emp in gridList select emp;

                    p_mother_check.Value = annesecilimi;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p_piece_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p_mother_check);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("p_rc", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                    OracleCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    this.gridPieceList.Visible = true;
                    gridPieceList.DataSource = dt;
                }
```

But I get an error in the procedure that returns value by oracle.

> OracleParameter value is invalid.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Z_LABEL_PRINTER_GR
AS
T_STRING_LIST DEFINAION : TYPE                "T_STRING_LIST" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000)    
PROCEDURE LabelPieceList(p_piece_id IN  T_STRING_LIST,
p_mother_check IN varchar2,
p_rc OUT sys_refcursor)
IS
    BEGIN
    IF p_mother_check='False' THEN
    OPEN p_rc FOR
    SELECT PIECE_NUM_ID,PIECE_ID,ACTUAL_WEIGHT,ACTUAL_THICK,ACTUAL_WIDTH 
    FROM piece WHERE PIECE_ID IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(p_piece_id))

    ELSE

    OPEN p_rc FOR
    SELECT PIECE_NUM_ID,PIECE_ID,ACTUAL_WEIGHT,ACTUAL_THICK,ACTUAL_WIDTH FROM piece WHERE PIECE_ID IN(
    (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(p_piece_id)) AND PH.STATUS=2);
    END IF ; 

    END LabelPieceList;

-- Package body
END Z_LABEL_PRINTER_GR;
```

Comment: I am not sure on this, but can you data converting the data to an array and then assign to value

Comment: In SQL Server you can achieve it using [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) but I dont know if oracle API does support them. I would suggest you giving a try and, if possible, letting us know if it worked.

Comment: @viveknuna No, you cannot do that. ADO.NET does not use arrays as DbTypes. You can either use a .net class (only in sql server) or structured data (tables and datareaders, could potentially work in oracle) Check [SqlDbTypes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Mother_check is also collection of array ? double check it.